# Save RGB Values for ML in Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, machine-learning, computer-vision

What's the optimal way (uses least storage) to save RGB values of images for machine learning training data in a SQL database? I'm using Postgres v13 and thinking of saving the data as a `text` column:

Below is an example of the data (values in the range of 0-255):

```
238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 65  71  108 77  115 179 84  128 192 119 163 222 43  48  87  48  54  89  42  46  81  45  50  83  49  54  85  238 238 238 52  86  152 70  102 167 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 60  63  94  86  132 196 98  142 206 111 155 219 113 157 220 107 151 215 49  54  87  52  54  88  39  43  79  233 236 240 83  125 194 72  104 157 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 63  65  99  66  72  107 101 145 209 98  142 205 102 144 209 107 152 213 105 149 212 46  51  84  50  52  86  238 238 238 82  124 191 75  113 177 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 98  137 199 86  128 195 168 149 139 46  52  89  61  67  104 61  67  107 54  57  95  46  48  83  42  46  81  47  50  81  76  115 180 79  121 189 240 238 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 90  124 179 97  137 202 120 149 216 89  65  53  160 147 138 48  53  86  48  52  87  39  41  76  46  48  83  90  128 193 115 154 216 110 123 153 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 111 146 210 172 146 132 179 153 136 186 157 135 109 99  92  143 109 89  107 77  60  89  129 191 104 142 206 80  120 179 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 164 134 112 178 149 128 137 110 89  159 130 109 148 111 83  83  62  60  152 118 104 59  68  78  109 145 205 63  90  154 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 193 180 171 165 137 116 153 127 110 168 137 116 164 132 109 116 86  67  172 146 126 160 129 108 153 123 105 164 136 118 143 123 106 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 158 135 120 144 120 102 167 140 123 132 103 83  148 117 92  126 90  72  137 106 81  141 112 91  146 116 96  143 117 97  164 133 107 234 239 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 145 122 106 187 165 147 154 135 120 151 128 112 152 128 106 90  82  75  136 105 84  134 103 80  177 148 127 169 138 117 155 130 114 150 131 110 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 134 108 88  182 160 142 170 147 131 171 148 132 142 116 99  87  71  58  140 114 98  162 134 116 147 122 102 170 146 128 172 146 129 165 140 124 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 152 124 107 163 141 123 133 109 89  117 113 126 150 122 105 117 103 97  160 128 109 154 124 105 168 143 123 170 147 131 165 142 126 158 134 116 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 176 152 134 181 159 141 179 160 145 150 130 113 136 114 96  106 85  70  235 241 240 156 129 109 155 129 112 161 142 127 187 163 145 167 143 123 237 238 242 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 147 122 106 153 133 116 185 164 149 143 123 106 144 122 104 128 100 80  238 238 238 164 134 115 170 144 127 157 134 118 156 133 117 162 139 118 239 237 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 155 129 112 175 154 139 157 136 121 152 137 116 144 122 103 231 238 246 238 238 238 137 107 88  159 132 115 135 109 92  158 137 121 155 133 117 155 138 121 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 148 123 103 186 164 148 145 121 103 129 103 86  113 99  81  241 239 238 238 238 238 132 104 87  147 121 103 150 128 110 163 143 126 148 122 105 158 129 108 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 139 114 97  156 136 120 149 128 111 130 110 92  150 130 112 231 241 235 238 238 238 233 225 220 163 135 116 174 149 132 144 123 106 148 124 106 165 139 120 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 135 104 89  175 154 139 151 129 111 142 116 99  165 141 119 240 238 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 124 96  80  142 116 99  178 152 135 157 133 115 160 134 117 127 105 94  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 140 117 101 151 128 112 129 106 90  142 116 99  158 132 108 234 239 240 238 238 238 238 238 238 118 98  87  128 103 83  144 120 102 117 92  72  171 143 126 123 97  81  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 165 145 127 149 122 102 135 109 92  130 108 90  168 142 122 238 243 242 238 238 238 238 238 238 153 130 115 139 111 94  151 126 110 135 108 88  120 93  73  150 124 107 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 175 156 141 141 117 95  155 128 108 144 112 93  140 115 95  132 122 104 238 238 238 238 238 238 142 117 101 143 117 101 124 96  80  173 143 124 147 117 98  157 130 110 164 142 130 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 150 122 105 153 127 107 160 133 113 143 116 96  156 132 114 136 112 94  238 238 238 238 238 238 156 142 130 123 96  76  147 117 98  92  73  58  163 137 120 165 138 118 173 153 142 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 154 131 109 113 89  71  153 123 104 150 124 107 124 99  79  136 120 107 238 238 238 238 238 238 120 95  79  166 138 121 112 83  62  153 125 108 103 78  62  150 124 108 185 161 145 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 145 115 96  136 106 86  120 96  78  158 131 110 124 99  79  96  88  82  238 238 238 238 238 238 205 190 183 140 110 91  149 120 105 152 122 103 145 113 93  132 104 87  190 161 139 215 209 202 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 155 131 112 141 115 98  135 111 93  145 120 100 157 133 111 106 97  84  238 238 238 238 238 238 234 239 237 140 116 94  143 113 96  139 105 82  151 120 97  170 138 116 117 87  68  164 138 121 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 122 95  75  142 113 92  136 104 84  161 136 118 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 149 124 104 148 120 103 140 114 96  169 141 124 155 128 107 133 98  78  138 105 85  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 177 162 146 154 143 145 120 110 112 151 119 100 163 159 154 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 154 132 120 131 107 87  124 97  77  127 101 77  119 101 98  246 232 234 150 126 106 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 237 237 237 226 218 221 231 206 194 201 171 158 174 174 174 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 236 236 236 219 219 219 198 198 198 173 173 173 229 222 225 219 212 217 222 216 221 237 237 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 235 235 235 231 231 231 231 231 231 236 236 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 229 229 229 212 193 187 211 192 189 193 175 162 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 237 237 237 237 237 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 65  71  108 77  115 179 84  128 192 119 163 222 43  48  87  48  54  89  42  46  81  45  50  83  49  54  85  238 238 238 52  86  152 70  102 167 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 60  63  94  86  132 196 98  142 206 111 155 219 113 157 220 107 151 215 49  54  87  52  54  88  39  43  79  233 236 240 83  125 194 72  104 157 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 63  65  99  66  72  107 101 145 209 98  142 205 102 144 209 107 152 213 105 149 212 46  51  84  50  52  86  238 238 238 82  124 191 75  113 177 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 98  137 199 86  128 195 168 149 139 46  52  89  61  67  104 61  67  107 54  57  95  46  48  83  42  46  81  47  50  81  76  115 180 79  121 189 240 238 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 90  124 179 97  137 202 120 149 216 89  65  53  160 147 138 48  53  86  48  52  87  39  41  76  46  48  83  90  128 193 115 154 216 110 123 153 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 111 146 210 172 146 132 179 153 136 186 157 135 109 99  92  143 109 89  107 77  60  89  129 191 104 142 206 80  120 179 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 164 134 112 178 149 128 137 110 89  159 130 109 148 111 83  83  62  60  152 118 104 59  68  78  109 145 205 63  90  154 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 193 180 171 165 137 116 153 127 110 168 137 116 164 132 109 116 86  67  172 146 126 160 129 108 153 123 105 164 136 118 143 123 106 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 158 135 120 144 120 102 167 140 123 132 103 83  148 117 92  126 90  72  137 106 81  141 112 91  146 116 96  143 117 97  164 133 107 234 239 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 145 122 106 187 165 147 154 135 120 151 128 112 152 128 106 90  82  75  136 105 84  134 103 80  177 148 127 169 138 117 155 130 114 150 131 110 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 134 108 88  182 160 142 170 147 131 171 148 132 142 116 99  87  71  58  140 114 98  162 134 116 147 122 102 170 146 128 172 146 129 165 140 124 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 152 124 107 163 141 123 133 109 89  117 113 126 150 122 105 117 103 97  160 128 109 154 124 105 168 143 123 170 147 131 165 142 126 158 134 116 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 176 152 134 181 159 141 179 160 145 150 130 113 136 114 96  106 85  70  235 241 240 156 129 109 155 129 112 161 142 127 187 163 145 167 143 123 237 238 242 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 147 122 106 153 133 116 185 164 149 143 123 106 144 122 104 128 100 80  238 238 238 164 134 115 170 144 127 157 134 118 156 133 117 162 139 118 239 237 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 155 129 112 175 154 139 157 136 121 152 137 116 144 122 103 231 238 246 238 238 238 137 107 88  159 132 115 135 109 92  158 137 121 155 133 117 155 138 121 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 148 123 103 186 164 148 145 121 103 129 103 86  113 99  81  241 239 238 238 238 238 132 104 87  147 121 103 150 128 110 163 143 126 148 122 105 158 129 108 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 139 114 97  156 136 120 149 128 111 130 110 92  150 130 112 231 241 235 238 238 238 233 225 220 163 135 116 174 149 132 144 123 106 148 124 106 165 139 120 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 135 104 89  175 154 139 151 129 111 142 116 99  165 141 119 240 238 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 124 96  80  142 116 99  178 152 135 157 133 115 160 134 117 127 105 94  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 140 117 101 151 128 112 129 106 90  142 116 99  158 132 108 234 239 240 238 238 238 238 238 238 118 98  87  128 103 83  144 120 102 117 92  72  171 143 126 123 97  81  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 165 145 127 149 122 102 135 109 92  130 108 90  168 142 122 238 243 242 238 238 238 238 238 238 153 130 115 139 111 94  151 126 110 135 108 88  120 93  73  150 124 107 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 175 156 141 141 117 95  155 128 108 144 112 93  140 115 95  132 122 104 238 238 238 238 238 238 142 117 101 143 117 101 124 96  80  173 143 124 147 117 98  157 130 110 164 142 130 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 150 122 105 153 127 107 160 133 113 143 116 96  156 132 114 136 112 94  238 238 238 238 238 238 156 142 130 123 96  76  147 117 98  92  73  58  163 137 120 165 138 118 173 153 142 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 154 131 109 113 89  71  153 123 104 150 124 107 124 99  79  136 120 107 238 238 238 238 238 238 120 95  79  166 138 121 112 83  62  153 125 108 103 78  62  150 124 108 185 161 145 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 145 115 96  136 106 86  120 96  78  158 131 110 124 99  79  96  88  82  238 238 238 238 238 238 205 190 183 140 110 91  149 120 105 152 122 103 145 113 93  132 104 87  190 161 139 215 209 202 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 155 131 112 141 115 98  135 111 93  145 120 100 157 133 111 106 97  84  238 238 238 238 238 238 234 239 237 140 116 94  143 113 96  139 105 82  151 120 97  170 138 116 117 87  68  164 138 121 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 122 95  75  142 113 92  136 104 84  161 136 118 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 149 124 104 148 120 103 140 114 96  169 141 124 155 128 107 133 98  78  138 105 85  238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 177 162 146 154 143 145 120 110 112 151 119 100 163 159 154 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 154 132 120 131 107 87  124 97  77  127 101 77  119 101 98  246 232 234 150 126 106 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 237 237 237 226 218 221 231 206 194 201 171 158 174 174 174 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 236 236 236 219 219 219 198 198 198 173 173 173 229 222 225 219 212 217 222 216 221 237 237 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 235 235 235 231 231 231 231 231 231 236 236 236 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 229 229 229 212 193 187 211 192 189 193 175 162 235 235 235 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 237 237 237 237 237 237 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238 238
```

The above space-separated RGB value will be converted to CSV outside of the database to be use as input (training data) to create the machine learning model.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to realize is *there is no optimal way* to store values when there is an option. Improvement in one aspect likely leads to extra work elsewhere. You must analyze the tradeoff and determine if it is worth the cost of the extra work. In this case though you are looking for *least storage* so let's look at some options. You are considering using text; **do not**. Storing numeric data as text is always a bad idea, but here it also requires the most storage (9 bytes for each RGB combination). In this case the easiest overall would be just create 3 columns in your table each defined as `smallint` (6 bytes for each RGB combination). Further all verification the range (0-255) for each is enforced in the database (check constraint). Any processing of individual values is straight forward. The next option, creating an array of `smallint`. With 3 values in each array (still 6 bytes and maybe? some array overhead). However, this requires keeping the index straight for individual processing and moves range validation from the database to the application code. But if storage size is the only criteria lets reduce it to storing a single integer (4 bytes).  

Consider your max value 255 is represented in hex as 'ff' (1 byte). So each RGB value can be represented as 1 byte in each byte of an integer as follows:

```
+-------+-----------------+-------------+
| Color |    Dec Rep.     |  Hex Rep.   |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+
| Red   | 000 255 000 000 | 00 ff 00 00 |
| Green | 000 000 255 000 | 00 00 ff 00 |
| Blue  | 000 000 000 255 | 00 00 00 ff |
+-------+-----------------+-------------+
```

This, however, requires extensive additional application or database (plpgsql) code. Shifting and bit processing to get each element into the correct location and extracting for individual processing. And all validation to the database/application. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=457830942727840c345289cacc21abde)).  

Reference: [Postgres Bit Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html)